# An if-statement based on src HTML

Tags: html, django, if-statement

I have big html document with various images with href and src.

I want to make an if statement based on the output of the src.

```
<img class="img-fluid d-block w-100" src="/static/assets/img/{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}/actionFlow({% if form.status.value|slugify == '1'%}taak-toegewezen{% else %}{{form.status.value|slugify}}{%endif%}).png" id="workflowVisual">
```

Example outputs can be:

"/static/assets/img/en/actionFlow(taak-toegewezen).png"
"/static/assets/img/en/actionFlow(firststep).png"

Now, I want to create an if statement like so:

```
 {% if src== "/static/assets/img/en/actionFlow(taak-toegewezen).png"}{{instance.reviewer2}}
 {% else src== "/static/assets/img/en/actionFlow(firststep).png"}{{instance.reviewer1}}{%endif%}
```

How do I do this in HTML?

Best,

Rob

Comment: You can use PHP or Js

Comment: What would be an example JS file? Sorry I am really lost

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use django templating, which is not just HTML.

You can set variables using `{% with variable = 1 %}`:

```
{% if form.status.value|slugify == '1' %}
    {% with SLUG = 'taak-toegewezen' %}
{% else %}
    {% with SLUG = form.status.value|slugify %}
{% endif %}

{% with imgSrc = "/static/assets/img/"|addstr:LANGUAGE_CODE|addstr:"/actionFlow("|addstr:SLUG|addstr:").png" %}
```

And now it's way easier to use in a if statement.

```
{% if imgSrc == "/static/assets/img/en/actionFlow(taak-toegewezen).png" %}
    {{instance.reviewer2 }}
{% else if imgSrc == "/static/assets/img/en/actionFlow(firststep).png" %}
    {{instance.reviewer1 }}
{% else %}
    Default value
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am using django and slugify. Now I will get the error that set is not present : django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 10: 'set'.

Comment: Should I install jinja?

Comment: I think the with statement will fix it

Comment: Thank you for your help Dylan. The error says TemplateSyntaxError at /action
'with' received an invalid token: '=='

Comment: Is it still the case ? I don't know if you answered after or before my edit

Comment: after your edit sir:)

Comment: Are you sure you have the same code ? as my last edit ? 
Django cannot parse if you do not have spaces before and after `==`, be sure you have spaces before and after your `==`